# Closing modal window on loaded event

Tags: c#, wpf

### The Environment :

The view need to load defaults from excel and limitations. the model is loaded from database. So the view is the collision between the 2. A binding update another one and another one and so on. Since the database is 99% stable i don't have trouble here but the excel source can change alot in a single day and sometime contain invalid data. So i decided to make the view receive the data from excel and propagate it to the models so they validate themselves along the way without crashing down. The models also make use a over 50 WCF services and network/anti virus sometime kill the connections so error get also thrown there. Again i did all the work of handling that and a single boolean in the models tells if everything went fine or not.

### The Problem :

The view HAS to be modal so i called it with a simple `MyWindow.ShowDialog();`.
when it's closed i request the model and pass it along the different object that need to consume it.

Now this works perfectly but when i have issues in the window itself (excel data passed to it) or 1 or multiple models (varies between 1 and 5 usually). It not very important but let me mention that those models are completely different to each other and are unrelated to each other some have less that 100 properties other over 4,000.

anyhow those model might trigger an event that says they are corrupted/invalid/unresponsive.
If only 1 don't function properly i must stop going on in this view. Now putting overlay with button saying "CLOSE" being the only click able thing was not accepted as a viable solution although very simple for me :).

So letting everything load i looked at what even i could use to check for the status and then pop a message box with some text explaining then automatically close the window. I found that the `Loaded` event suits my need and in fact i breakpoint there and the models are well completed. I am able to show a litle message without problem but the `this.Close();` is not ... cooperating.

The `this.Close();` throw the error `Hwnd of zero is not valid.` on the `MyWindow.ShowDialog();`. I did put a try catch over it and it works but i mean it's not a solution. Trying to close before the `Show();` or `ShowDialog();` throws and error and i understand but where would it be possible to call a `This.Close();` without user interaction ?

Hell, I tried a timer after the loaded to do the job to face palm myself after remembering timer is a thread and an external thread can't call the close.

Edit : I will add that i am not reading the modal result right away

```
MyWindow.ShowDialog(); // <-- crash here but on F11 it goes in loaded then when loaded finsih it crash. seems like issue when show dialog return.

if (MyWindow.DialogResult == true)
{
    // .....
}
```

Comment: Try setting `DialogResult = false;` *before* you close your dialog `Window`.

Comment: Doesn't help, still have the error.

Comment: `simple for me :)` <-- this smiley symbol shows that you're still optimistic and the problem is still in your control, it doesn't seem urgent or serious. That's great! I'm pretty sure that you can solve this yourself!

Comment: I found other solution people did an they put the window transparent then attached a mouse over event and move the mouse on top of the windows which trigger the event after the loaded then close the window properly. i am pretty sure there is a simpler way to do this. My coworkers here are also clueless but we all find a nasty try catch still better than that mouse hover crazy idea.

Comment: I tried this in a sample app `Loaded += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("I am going to close now");
                    Close();
                };` - didnt throw any errors for me. Your problem may be somewhere else?

Comment: I know it should work right. But it doesn't I did a test app too with the same form control (Syncfusion Chromeless Window) and it works too. I copy pasted my code and it works. i just know that if i comment out the `this.Close();` the loaded event finishes and with F11 it brings me back on the `ShowDialog();` (so it DOES return) and then crash with that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated another project with exact copy of the code and it works as long as no databinding exists. as soon as databinding exist the `.ShowDialog();` fails on the return. I just switched the chromeless window for standard window and bang everything works. Another syncfusion bug that they deny being a bug. They call it "intended behavior".